# How to check if $x^{21} + 2x^8 + 1$ and $x^{21} + 2x^9 + 1$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The full question is to answer if these two polynomials have multiple zeros. There is a theorem in my book that says that if $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $\operatorname{char}(F) = p ≠ 0$ then $f(x)$ has multiple zeros only if $f(x) = g(x^p)$ for some $g(x) \in F[x]$.

This last condition is easy to check for, since the exponents of the first polynomial have $gcd(21, 8) = 1$ while the second polynomial has $gcd(21, 9) = 3$ therefore the second polynomial should have a multiple zero but only if it is irreducible.

How can I check if either of these polynomials are irreducible?

Comment: Well, the second is $(x^7+2x^3+1)^3.$

Comment: It's easy  to check for zeroes $\pmod 3$, no?  Anyway, with a computer it is easy to factor both of them...not sure it's easy by hand.

Comment: The first one is $(x^7 + 2 x^5 + x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x + 2) (x^{14} + x^{12} + 2 x^{11} + 2 x^{10} + x^9 + 2 x^8 + 2 x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + 2 x^4 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^2 + x + 2) \pmod 3$, though, again, this was done with a computer.

Comment: Your title asks about irreducible, the body asks for multiple zeros. And I have no idea what the theorem actually says, but what you have in your question is not a true theorem. Can you state *exactly* what the theorem says?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The theorem says "Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$. If $F$ has characteristic $0$ then $f(x)$ has no multiple zeros. If $F$ has characteristic $p ≠ 0$ then $f(x)$ has a multiple zero only if it is of the form $f(x) = g(x^p)$ in $F[x]." This is from chapter 20 of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @lulu What software did you use to determine that?

Comment: But if $f(x)=g(x^p)$ over $\mathbb Z_p$, then $f(x)$ is not irreducible, since $f(x)=(g(x))^p$, so that theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: As a rule, this is why your entire question should be in the body. I was confused about the irreducible in the title and the theorem in the body because you didn't state that $f$ was irreducible in the body, and I knew that in this case if $f(x)=g(x^p)$ then $f$ is not irreducible, so I wasn't sure what you were saying.

Comment: Yea, that's why I'm wondering how to go about factorizing some of these polynomials. It looks as though the way to go is to use some software package to derive the factorization.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Wolfram Alpha to factor the polynomials:

For $x^{21} + 2x^8 + 1$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E21+%2B+2x%5E8+%2B+1

For $x^{21} + 2x^9 + 1$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E21+%2B+2x%5E9+%2B+1

For both pages, scroll to the bottom to find the factorization in $GF_3$